# Embed a font into PDF form

Tags: linux, pdf, fonts, pdf-generation

I have a PDF form generated by LibreOffice. Since to a [known bug](https://www.libreoffice.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50879) in LibreOffice only a font subset is embedded into PDF even when the font is used in form fields. Therefore the form is not usable or form fields are using a wrong front (depending on PDF viewer) if the font is not installed on computer.

So I have to replace form subset in PDF form by whole font after generation in LibreOffice. Normally using `ps2pdf` or `gs` is recommended to fix a font issue in a pdf. But both programs don't support PDF form. If using them on a PDF form the form fields are broken. I tested it with Ghostscript 9.10 under Unbunt 14.04 LTS.

I can use `pdffonts` to show fonts embedded in PDF. But is there also a command-line tool to embed another font into a PDF?

Answer (score 1):

Libreoffice v5.2 embedding fonts for forms fields is easy:

Enable the font in the form field:
() Right-click form field > Control > Font

Then tell your document to include the used fonts into its file:
() File > Properties > Font tab > Embed fonts into document
In my case filesize increases from 50k to 5000k (using one font 
with two styles).

At last check PDF options to include fonts into pdf:
() File > Export to Pdf > General tab:
x Enable Create PDF form (to make the form fields fill-in ready to the user). 
Not shure whether both of the following options are needed: 
x Tagged PDF and 
x Hybrid PDF: The later will enlarge pdf to the size of the LibreOffice file.

Answer (score 1):

Until the bug gets resolved, you can use [PDF Toolbelt](https://github.com/george-hopkins/pdf-toolbelt) to fix your forms.

After downloading the JAR file, the font of all fields can be reset to the default values of Adobe Acrobat:

```
java -jar ./pdf-toolbelt.jar form-font-defaults input.pdf output.pdf
```

---

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the above-mentioned tool.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a workaround: place a text edit field on the page that is invisible and locked which contains a default string of your likely character set. While you will still get a subset font, it would be a substantially larger subset.

Comment: In my tests, Acrobat Reader DC only accepts the font for the form fields if it's fully embedded (not a subset), regardless of how many characters are there. It makes sense, since a form filler reader that could not display an arbitrary character not in the font would be a terrible behavior for the user.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of commercial solutions that can fully embed a font in a PDF, if a commercial application is a viable option in your case (they will be expensive to "just" do this probably). The two major contenders are probably callas pdfToolbox (caution: I'm associated with this product) and Enfocus Pitstop.